# why javascript string replace using regex removes a "/" from my br tag

Tags: javascript, regex, str-replace

I'm using javascript with a super simple regex to replace a "<" with the HTML character code for it so I can place some code on my site using the pre and code tags and have it done automatically.

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/FranciscoG/JWqvp/1/)

basically I'm trying to figure out why this js code:

```
var str = document.getElementById("cleanme").innerHTML;
str=str.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
document.getElementById("cleanme").innerHTML = str;
```

removes the "/" in the br tag

```
<pre><code id="cleanme">
<p><br />this is some code</p>
</code></pre>
```

not a huge deal because I'm just displaying code, but I'd still like to know.

it outputs this:

```
<p><br>this is some code</p>
```

thanks

Comment: How are you seeing it returns just <br>? javascript alerts? chrome inspect element?

Comment: Through the browswer by implementing it in a webpage, also through the "result" panel in jsFiddle, and also through a javascript alert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it has to do with the way certain browsers return the innerHTML property. If you use Google Chrome, inspect any < br/ > tag using the debugging tools and you'll notice they don't show a backslash. The same is true when Chrome returns an innerHTML property, the blackslash is stripped out.

So when you pass in:

```
<pre><code id="cleanme">
<p><br />this is some code</p>
</code></pre>
```

The browser return an innerHTML property of:

```
<pre><code id="cleanme">
<p><br>this is some code</p>
</code></pre>
```

Your RegEx is not the issue.

Comment: ahhhh I see your point.  is there another property besides innerHTML that get's the exact code instead of the browser's interpretation of the code?  I'm not adversed to jQuery if that makes things easier.

Comment: slash: Unicode U+002F = '/' . . . . . backslash: Unicode U+005C = '\'

Comment: For chrome, I don't think there's anyway around this...at least that I know of. If you don't want a browser to mess with the <code> block escape it on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is OK.

If you try this:

```
var str = '<p><br />this is some code</p>';
str=str.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
str=str.replace(/>/g,"&gt;");
document.getElementById("cleanme").innerHTML = str;
```

It'll correctly print `<br />`.

Possibly it's effect of browser's HTML normalization.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too late to help you, and you've accepted a correct answer, but there's another big potential problem.
I tried this with Firefox 3.6.11 on Linux and 3.6.12 on Windows and they both behaved the same --

I did not see the `<p><br>this is some code</p>` in the Result pane on your fiddle, instead I saw simply `this is some code` with no markup at all.

Throwing firebug at it by adding a `debugger;` statement as the first line in the JavaScript pane and tracing through it, I found that `str` was getting a value of `'\n'`, that is, just a newline was being returned from `innerHTML` and nothing else.

Thinking about this, but with no way to confirm it, I suspect it's because Firefox is building the DOM tree differently than you expect, because the HTML you're using is *invalid*. Inline elements are not allowed to contain block elements; specifically, the `<code>` tag is not allowed to contain a `<p>` tag, and `<pre>` is likewise not allowed to contain a `<p>` tag -- again, only limited inline elements can be used inside a `<pre>` tag).

I think FF is implicitly closing the code block before opening the paragraph so the innerHTML of `id="cleanme"` is nothing but the newline. It renders with the "pre" font as you expect because you've thrown the browser into Quirks Mode.

Comment: i'm seeing that now too.  thanks.  Wonder if I could wrap the code in a div with the id="cleanme" and then run the js first, replacing the < and > and then have js add in the pre and code opening and closing tags.  wonder if that would help.

Comment: just checked it on Firefox 4 and it's working like it did for me on Chrome.  Must be older versions of FF.  Still, I will try and fix it

Comment: like this:  `document.getElementById("cleanme").innerHTML = "<pre><code>" + str + "</code></pre>";`  and I've turned "cleanme" into a div

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML does not return the literal source code, but the result of the browser's interpretation of it.

Different browsers will return very different results for innerHTML, sometimes omitting some quotes and 'optional' end tags, capitalizing some tag names and attributes, and collapsing extra white-space.

And HTML does not close open tags that can't have end tags, so they are not included either.